# Passing 'Custom' Value back from Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I'm attempting to pass order IDs to Paypal from an order page, then back to the thanks page so I can mark an order as paid, but I'm running into problems. Currently I'm passing these variables to Paypal like this:

```
$vars = array(

'cmd' => "_cart",
'upload' => "1",
'business' => "paypalemail@gmail.com",
'item_name_1' => "Test Item",
'amount_1' => "1.00",
'return' => "http://www.website.com/thanks.php",
'custom' => $order_id,



);

header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?' . http_build_query($vars));
```

When they payment clears and I'm redirected, it doesn't appear that the order id is being sent back, however. This is the url I'm given:

```
thanks.php?tx=61G92224EW780500P&st=Completed&amt=1.00&cc=USD&cm=57&item_number=
```

I expected to see a "custom=" followed by the order number somewhere in this string. But it isn't present. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: you use IPN to determine if a payment if made, never the return url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working on the same today :-)

You obviously want to use PDT instead of IPN, there are in fact some cases when this makes sense (e.g. small stores). PayPal PDT returns ONLY the tx value in GET format. It then expects that you construct a POST containing:

- tx you just received
- id token of the account
- cmd with the fixed value "_notify-synch"

Only this post is answered with a body containing the variables, one each line.

See https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/en_US/files/developer/PP_OrderMgmt_IntegrationGuide.pdf page 19.

Comment: Thank you :) The link you sent has just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not getting the 'custom' GET parameter is because for some reason on the return URL, PayPal renames it to 'cm' so in the original example above, I assume that the custom parameter had been sent to PayPal will a value of 57 and you can see cm=57 in the return URL.
I think the custom parameter is still called 'custom' in the IPN call.

Comment: Thanks! that was it. Saved me some time.